# How do I map each passenger to respective bus no based on arrival time of passenger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

It would be great if someone help to solve below puzzle.
I have buss & passenger details based on arrival time of each passenger to bus stop. Who will onboard to which bus and count of the passengers to each bus?

```
create table test_t1(bus_no int,orgn varchar(20),dest varchar(25),start_tm time)
go
insert into test_t1
select 1,'Delhi','Noida','10:00' union all
select 2,'Delhi','Agra','10:30' union all
select 3,'Delhi','Noida','11:00' union all
select 4,'Delhi','Noida','16:00'
go
select * from test_t1


create table test_t2(pass_no int,orgn varchar(20),dest varchar(25),arrvl_tm time)

    insert into test_t2
    select '1','Delhi','Noida','9:00' union all
    select '2','Delhi','Noida','9:30' union all
    select '3','Delhi','Noida','10:30' union all
    select '4','Delhi','Noida','11:30' union all
    select '5','Delhi','Noida','12:30' union all
    select '6','Delhi','Noida','14:00' union all
    select '7','Delhi','Noida','18:00' union all
    select '8','Delhi','Agra','9:00' union all
    select '9','Delhi','Agra','10:00' union all
    select '10','Delhi','Agra','12:00'
    
    select * from test_t2
```

Tried below query but didn't work. Seems something I am missing.

```
select *,
case when  t22.start_tm between t11.min_arrvl_tm and t11.max_arrvl_tm then t22.bus_no else 9999 end as mapp
from (

select pass_no,orgn,dest,arrvl_tm,arrvl_tm as min_arrvl_tm,isnull(LEAD(arrvl_tm) over(order by pass_no),arrvl_tm) max_arrvl_tm from test_t2

) as t11 cross join test_t1 t22
```

Expected Output.

[image]

Comment: So, for the sample data you have provided, what are your expected results? What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: What do you mean "below is the same"?

Comment: I have edited initial question by adding expected output. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: String aggregation is a *pain* on older version of SQL Server; are you really still using 2012? It only has about 2 weeks left of extended support left.

Comment: Unfortunately yes still we are using 2012 and migrating to SQL server 2017 by end of August.

Comment: How do you know what person got on what bus? There were 3 buses to Noida, from Delhi, which did pass_no 4 get on, and how do *you* know?

Comment: Based on arrival time (Arrvl_tm in test_t2 table) of passenger to bus stop. If the passenger arrives to bus stop before bus start time then he will onboard to available bus, otherwise wait and onboard next bus.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you make a better relationship between the tables, ideally a foreign key constraint to the `BusNo`, rather than the necessity to `JOIN` on the origin, destination, and a fuzzy time.

Answer (score 1):

This is, honestly, ugly. Firstly, there is no relationship between the passengers and the bus they board; you don't know what one they did you have to *guess* based on the origin, destination and time. This means that I have to use 2 CTEs to get the relational data.

Next, you are on an old version of means you need to use the old `FOR XML PATH` method for your string aggregation. As such, this results in 2 scans of both tables, and for a larger dataset is unlikely to be performant:

```sql
WITH IncompleteRelationship AS(
    SELECT tt1.bus_no,
           tt1.orgn,
           tt1.dest,
           tt1.start_tm,
           tt2.pass_no,
           tt2.arrvl_tm,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tt2.pass_no ORDER BY tt1.start_tm) AS RN
    FROM dbo.test_t1 tt1
         LEFT JOIN dbo.test_t2 tt2 ON tt1.orgn = tt2.orgn
                                  AND tt1.dest = tt2.dest
                                  AND tt1.start_tm > tt2.arrvl_tm),
Top1PerGroup AS(
    SELECT IR.bus_no,
           IR.orgn,
           IR.dest,
           IR.start_tm,
           IR.pass_no,
           IR.arrvl_tm
    FROM IncompleteRelationship IR
    WHERE RN = 1)
SELECT T1PG.bus_no,
       T1PG.orgn,
       T1PG.dest,
       T1PG.start_tm,
       COUNT(*) AS Passengers,
       STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',',SA.pass_no)
              FROM Top1PerGroup SA
              WHERE T1PG.bus_no = SA.bus_no
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS PassNumbers
FROM Top1PerGroup T1PG
GROUP BY T1PG.bus_no,
         T1PG.orgn,
         T1PG.dest,
         T1PG.start_tm;
```

On a newer version of SQL Server, and with a good relationship defined, this would be much easier:

```sql
SELECT tt1.bus_no,
       tt1.orgn,
       tt1.dest,
       tt1.start_tm,
       COUNT(tt2.pass_no) AS Passengers,
       STRING_AGG(tt2.pass_no,',') AS PassNumbers
FROM dbo.test_t1 tt1
     LEFT JOIN dbo.test_t2 tt2 ON tt1.bus_no = tt2.bus_no
GROUP BY tt1.bus_no,
         tt1.orgn,
         tt1.dest,
         tt1.start_tm;
```

Comment: Thank you Larnu for your help. Your code helps a lot. Let me test from my end with huge data.

Comment: @Larnu Can you please help me understand the logic behind that row_number?Please.Thank you so much in advance